# Фильтр списка по коллекции строк

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Необходимо отфильтровать список пользователей по списку параметров, пример

```
 List<String> regions = Arrays.asList("r02", "r05", "r09"); // список параметров

    //добавляем тестовых юзеров
    List<UserDto> userDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setRegion("r0" + i);
        userDtos.add(userDto);
    }

    userDtos.stream().filter(r->r.getRegion().equals(regions)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

По идее мы должны найти двух юзеров с `r02` и `r05`. Результат - пустой массив.

Подскажите как правильно отфильтровать, что бы получить коллекцию юзеров из списка параметров фильтра?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сравниваете в quals два разных типа объектов - String и ArrayList. А вам нужно проверять, входит ли String в ваш List:

```
userDtos.stream().filter(r->regions.contains(r.getRegion())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Вы правы, благодарю! Буду внимательней))